# File Process in C

Tags: c, file, process

I wrote these codes for my project but I have error in these codes.
This function's purpose is to add new client in this file. When I process it, it's okay but if I want to see my clients from file I process search function it gets to me more than my clients like that. I tried to work it by using fscanf but when I tried it, my addition function isn't working completely because it is not read 'kisiler.iz' (means registration track).
[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9ocC.png)

```
void ekle(struct kisiyapi kisiler)
{
    char secenek;
    dosya=fopen("kisiler.txt","a+");
    do
        {
        kisiler.iz=' '; 
        printf("Kisi no giriniz\n");
        scanf("%d",&kisiler.kisino);
        kaypos=(kisiler.kisino-1) * sizeof(kisiler);
        fseek(dosya,kaypos,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&kisiler,sizeof(kisiler),1,dosya);
        if(kisiler.iz!='*')
        {
        printf("Kisinin adini giriniz\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.ad);
        printf("Kisinin soyadini giriniz\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.soyad);
        printf("Kisinin Ev Telefonunu giriniz\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.evtel);
        printf("Kisinin Cep Telefonunu giriniz\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.ceptel);
        printf("Kisinin Is Telefonunu giriniz\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.istel);
        printf("Kisinin Dogum tarihini sirasiyla gun/ay/yil olarak giriniz\n");
        scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumgunu);
        scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumayi);
        scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumyili);
        printf("Kisinin yasadigi Il girin\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.il);
        printf("Kisinin yasadigi Ilce girin\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.ilce);
        printf("Kisinin yasadigi mahalleyi girin\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.mahalle);
        printf("Kisinin yasadigi sokak no girin\n");
        scanf("%s",&kisiler.sokak); 
        kisiler.iz='*';
        fseek(dosya,kaypos,SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&kisiler,sizeof(kisiler),1,dosya);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Mevcut kayit var\n");
        }
        printf("\nTekrar ekleme yapmak istiyor musunuz ? [e veya h]");
        secenek=getch();

        }
        while(secenek!='h');
    fclose(dosya);
}
```

and these codes' purpose is update information of any client but it's not working because my `feof` loop isn't working or work forever.
Therefore, I can't update my informations.

```
void guncelle(struct kisiyapi kisiler)
{

    char aranan[20];
    int i=0;
    dosya=fopen("kisiler.txt","r");
    yeni=fopen("temp.txt","w");
    if(dosya==NULL)
        printf("Dosyaya ulasilamadi\n");
    printf("Guncellemek istediginiz kisinin adini giriniz\n");
    scanf("%s",aranan);

    while(!feof(dosya))
    {
        i++;
    }
    /*
    while(!feof(dosya))
    {
        fread(&kisiler,sizeof(kisiler),1,dosya);
        kaypos=(kisiler.kisino-1) * sizeof(kisiler);
        if(strcmp(aranan,kisiler.ad)==0)
        {
            printf("Kisinin adini giriniz\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.ad);
            printf("Kisinin soyadini giriniz\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.soyad);
            printf("Kisinin Ev Telefonunu giriniz\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.evtel);
            printf("Kisinin Cep Telefonunu giriniz\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.ceptel);
            printf("Kisinin Is Telefonunu giriniz\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.istel);
            printf("Kisinin Dogum tarihini sirasiyla gun/ay/yil olarak giriniz\n");
            scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumgunu);
            scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumayi);
            scanf("%d",&kisiler.dogumyili);
            printf("Kisinin yasadigi Il girin\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.il);
            printf("Kisinin yasadigi Ilce girin\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.ilce);
            printf("Kisinin yasadigi mahalleyi girin\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.mahalle);
            printf("Kisinin yasadigi sokak no girin\n");
            scanf("%s",&kisiler.sokak); 
            kisiler.iz='*';
            fseek(yeni,kaypos,SEEK_SET);
            fprintf(dosya,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%d %d %d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%c",kisiler.ad,kisiler.soyad,kisiler.evtel,kisiler.ceptel,kisiler.istel
            ,*kisiler.dogumgunu,*kisiler.dogumayi,*kisiler.dogumyili,kisiler.il,kisiler.ilce,kisiler.mahalle,kisiler.sokak,kisiler.iz);
        }

        else if(strcmp(aranan,kisiler.ad)!=0)
        {
            fseek(yeni,kaypos,SEEK_SET);
            fseek(dosya,kaypos,SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&kisiler,sizeof(kisiler),1,yeni);
        }

    }

    fclose(dosya);
    fclose(yeni);
    */
}
```

If you understand my codes please help me I have no time to prepare it.

Comment: `while(!feof(dosya)) { i++; }` is almost certainly not going to produce the results you're telling us this code produces... Which book are you reading?

Comment: Saying "If you understand my codes please help me I have no time to prepare it" is not a good attitude — we're under no obligation to help you meet your homework time crunch.

Comment: I'm sorry I misspelled my English so bad.
I meant I didn't have time.
@JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 2):

The "eof" flag is only set once you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Your loop doesn't read *anything* from the file so it will never reach the end and will continue forever.

And very much related, you should read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: I want to ask somethink more,

Comment: @B.Yalcin If you want to ask something more, you're welcome to post new questions.